# Neo4j import performance

Tags: performance, neo4j, graph, cypher, query-performance

I have a Neo4j 3.5.3 installation on my Ubuntu laptop (which is Intel i5, 4 GB RAM, SSD disk) and I'm trying to import a moderate-sized dataset from CSV files into the graph.

Here is the full Cypher script I use:

```
MATCH (x :Shop ) DETACH DELETE x RETURN count(*) AS DeletedShops;
MATCH (x :Postal ) DETACH DELETE x RETURN count(*) AS DeletedPostal;
MATCH (x :City ) DETACH DELETE x RETURN count(*) AS DeletedCities;
MATCH (x :Locator ) DETACH DELETE x RETURN count(*) AS DeletedLocators;
MATCH (x :Brand ) DETACH DELETE x RETURN count(*) AS DeletedBrands;
MATCH (x :Industry ) DETACH DELETE x RETURN count(*) AS DeletedIndustries;

USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///accounts.csv.gz' AS csv
//locatorschemaname,accountname,clientname,clientindustry,accountindustry,locationcount
MERGE (b:Brand {name: csv.clientname})
FOREACH(n IN (CASE WHEN csv.clientindustry IS NOT NULL AND NOT toLower(csv.clientindustry) IN ['na','unknown','other'] THEN [1] ELSE [] END) |
  MERGE (i:Industry {name: csv.clientindustry})
  MERGE (b)-[:INDUSTRY]->(i)
)
FOREACH(n IN (CASE WHEN csv.accountindustry IS NOT NULL AND NOT toLower(csv.accountindustry) IN ['na','unknown','other'] THEN [1] ELSE [] END) |
  MERGE (i2:Industry {name: csv.accountindustry})
  MERGE (b)-[:INDUSTRY]->(i2)
)
// Brand.shops = max(locator.shops)
FOREACH(n IN (CASE WHEN csv.locatorschemaname IS NOT NULL AND csv.locatorschemaname=csv.accountname THEN [1] ELSE [] END) |
  MERGE (l:Locator {name: csv.locatorschemaname, shops: toInt(csv.locationcount)})
  MERGE (l)-[:BRAND]->(b)
  SET b.shops = CASE
    WHEN b.shops IS NULL OR b.shops < toInt(csv.locationcount) THEN toInt(csv.locationcount) ELSE b.shops END
);

MATCH (:Industry) RETURN count(*) AS IndustriesCreated;
MATCH (:Brand) RETURN count(*) AS BrandsCreated;
MATCH (:Locator) RETURN count(*) AS LocatorsCreated;

// Industry.shops = sum(Brand.shops)
MATCH (b:Brand)-[:INDUSTRY]->(i:Industry)
WITH i.name AS iname, sum(b.shops) AS isum
MATCH (ii:Industry {name: iname})
SET ii.shops = isum;

// NOTE: This is done in multiple-pass mode, to avoid performance issues with NEo4j CE 3.4.7 on ubuntu
// NOTE: We do not use WITH HEADERS as it adds a 40%+ overhead

// PASS 1. Shops
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///locations.csv.gz' AS csv
// schemaname,clientkey,name,address1,address2,city,region,country,postalcode,latitude,longitude
// find existing locator node
MATCH (l :Locator {name: csv[0]})
CREATE (s:Shop {
    locatorname: csv[0],
    clientkey: csv[1],
    latitude: toFloat(csv[9]),
    longitude: toFloat(csv[10])
})
CREATE (s)-[:LOCATOR]->(l);

CREATE INDEX ON :Shop (locatorname, clientkey);

MATCH (:Shop) RETURN count(*) AS ShopsCreated;

// PASS 2. cities
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///locations.csv.gz' AS csv
WITH csv WHERE csv[5] IS NOT NULL
MATCH (s:Shop {locatorname: csv[0], clientkey: csv[1]})
MERGE (city :City {name: csv[5], country: csv[7]}) ON CREATE SET city.region = csv[6]
MERGE (s)-[:CITY]->(city);

MATCH (:City) RETURN count(*) AS CitiesCreated;

// PASS 3. postal codes
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///locations.csv.gz' AS csv
WITH csv WHERE csv[8] IS NOT NULL
MATCH (s:Shop {locatorname: csv[0], clientkey: csv[1]})
MERGE (postal :Postal {name: csv[8], country: csv[7]}) ON CREATE SET postal.region = csv[6]
MERGE (s)-[:POSTAL]->(postal);

MATCH (:Postal) RETURN count(*) AS PostalcodesCreated;

CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (i:Industry) ASSERT i.name IS UNIQUE;
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (b:Brand) ASSERT b.name IS UNIQUE;
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (l:Locator) ASSERT l.name IS UNIQUE;
```

The problem is, the scripts makes it fairly quickly to the end of "PASS 1", and then it apparently hangs on "PASS 2". The server process is churning  CPU and nothing visible happens. This lasts at least 120 minutes and does not look like it's going to finish any time soon.

I use default settings for heap size etc. But on-disk size of the whole dataset (checked in /var/lib/neo4j/data) is ~~ 500 MB. So this machine should handle it.

Here is the output so far:

```
DeletedShops
0
DeletedPostal
0
DeletedCities
0
DeletedLocators
0
DeletedBrands
0
DeletedIndustries
0

IndustriesCreated
18
BrandsCreated
1326
LocatorsCreated
2092    

ShopsCreated
937488

// very long wait here
```

And here is some `ps` output:

```
[11:50:56][filip@lap2:~/neo4j]$ ps fuwww `pidof java`
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
filip     4966  0.0  0.1 3979904 7412 pts/0    Sl+  08:57   0:09 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -jar /usr/bin/../share/cypher-shell/lib/cypher-shell-all.jar -u neo4j -p neo --format plain
neo4j     2411 98.1 25.6 4862652 1012488 ?     Ssl  08:50 177:11 /usr/bin/java -cp /var/lib/neo4j/plugins:/etc/neo4j:/usr/share/neo4j/lib/*:/var/lib/neo4j/plugins/* -server -Xms950m -Xmx950m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+TrustFinalNonStaticFields -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true -Dunsupported.dbms.udc.source=debian -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 org.neo4j.server.CommunityEntryPoint --home-dir=/var/lib/neo4j --config-dir=/etc/neo4j
```

How can I rewrite the script to achieve same thing faster?

What can I do to diagnose the bottleneck?

Is this at all doable using limited (1-2 GB) java heap size - and why not?

**Update**: here is result of a short `strace -v -tt -f -s 100 -p <PID_OF_SERVER>`:

```
5020  13:04:53.108793 epoll_wait(238,  <unfinished ...>
5013  13:04:53.108847 epoll_wait(235,  <unfinished ...>
4887  13:04:53.108865 epoll_wait(232,  <unfinished ...>
4879  13:04:53.108874 epoll_wait(229,  <unfinished ...>
4617  13:04:53.108890 epoll_wait(226,  <unfinished ...>
4590  13:04:53.108897 epoll_wait(223,  <unfinished ...>
3557  13:04:53.108916 restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted futex ...> <unfinished ...>
3016  13:04:53.108925 restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted restart_syscall ...> <unfinished ...>
3015  13:04:53.108942 restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted restart_syscall ...> <unfinished ...>
3014  13:04:53.108950 restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted restart_syscall ...> <unfinished ...>
3013  13:04:53.108966 accept(256,  <unfinished ...>
3012  13:04:53.108981 epoll_wait(263,  <unfinished ...>
3011  13:04:53.108998 epoll_wait(260,  <unfinished ...>
3010  13:04:53.109006 accept(248,  <unfinished ...>
3009  13:04:53.109023 epoll_wait(255,  <unfinished ...>
3008  13:04:53.109032 epoll_wait(252,  <unfinished ...>
3007  13:04:53.109047 restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted restart_syscall ...> <unfinished ...>
3005  13:04:53.109055 epoll_wait(220,  <unfinished ...>
3001  13:04:53.109083 futex(0x7efc2999783c, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
3000  13:04:53.109098 futex(0x7efc29995d0c, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
2999  13:04:53.109116 futex(0x7efc2996e7d8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
2998  13:04:53.109125 futex(0x7efc2996eb68, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
2997  13:04:53.109141 restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted futex ...> <unfinished ...>
2996  13:04:53.109149 restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted futex ...> <unfinished ...>
2995  13:04:53.109166 restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted futex ...> <unfinished ...>
2994  13:04:53.109174 futex(0x7efc298c8df8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
2993  13:04:53.109190 restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted futex ...> <unfinished ...>
2992  13:04:53.109198 restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted futex ...> <unfinished ...>
2991  13:04:53.109214 restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted restart_syscall ...> <unfinished ...>
2990  13:04:53.109222 restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted restart_syscall ...> <unfinished ...>
2989  13:04:53.109239 restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted futex ...> <unfinished ...>
2951  13:04:53.109248 restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted futex ...> <unfinished ...>
2950  13:04:53.109266 futex(0x7efc2843f37c, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
2949  13:04:53.109274 restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted futex ...> <unfinished ...>
2948  13:04:53.109290 restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted futex ...> <unfinished ...>
2947  13:04:53.109299 restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted futex ...> <unfinished ...>
2946  13:04:53.109316 futex(0x7efc30ba6580, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 0, NULL, 0xffffffff <unfinished ...>
2945  13:04:53.109325 futex(0x7efc2842bb7c, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
2932  13:04:53.109342 futex(0x7efc283f3f7c, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
2927  13:04:53.109351 futex(0x7efc283f157c, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
2924  13:04:53.109369 restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted futex ...> <unfinished ...>
2621  13:04:53.109377 futex(0x7efc28048278, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
2620  13:04:53.109395 futex(0x7efc28046578, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
2619  13:04:53.109405 futex(0x7efc2803607c, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
2618  13:04:53.109423 futex(0x7efc28034378, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
2617  13:04:53.109432 futex(0x7efc2803277c, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
2616  13:04:53.109449 futex(0x7efc28030b7c, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
2615  13:04:53.109458 restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted futex ...> <unfinished ...>
2614  13:04:53.109476 futex(0x7efc2802c67c, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
2613  13:04:53.109485 futex(0x7efc2802aa78, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
2612  13:04:53.109507 futex(0x7efc28028e78, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
2611  13:04:53.109517 futex(0x7efc28027278, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
2610  13:04:53.109536 futex(0x7efc2800fb78, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
2411  13:04:53.109545 futex(0x7efc317f19d0, FUTEX_WAIT, 2610, NULL <unfinished ...>
2992  13:04:53.115544 <... restart_syscall resumed> ) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
2992  13:04:53.115730 futex(0x7efc2872dd78, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
2992  13:04:53.115828 futex(0x7efc2872ddc8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=9998460} <unfinished ...>
2997  13:04:53.118313 <... restart_syscall resumed> ) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
2997  13:04:53.118352 futex(0x7efc298e0128, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
2997  13:04:53.118394 futex(0x7efc298e0178, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=99998722} <unfinished ...>
2951  13:04:53.125119 <... restart_syscall resumed> ) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
2951  13:04:53.125180 futex(0x7efc28442a28, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
2951  13:04:53.125217 futex(0x7efc28442a78, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=49998764} <unfinished ...>
2992  13:04:53.126016 <... futex resumed> ) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
2992  13:04:53.126360 futex(0x7efc2872dd78, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
2992  13:04:53.126435 futex(0x7efc2872ddc8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=9996862}) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
2992  13:04:53.136631 futex(0x7efc2872dd78, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
2992  13:04:53.136735 futex(0x7efc2872ddc8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=9997659}) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
2992  13:04:53.146911 futex(0x7efc2872dd78, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
2992  13:04:53.147016 futex(0x7efc2872ddc8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=9998199}) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
2992  13:04:53.157194 futex(0x7efc2872dd78, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
2992  13:04:53.157259 futex(0x7efc2872ddc8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=9998611}) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
2992  13:04:53.167441 futex(0x7efc2872dd78, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
2992  13:04:53.167505 futex(0x7efc2872ddc8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=9998486} <unfinished ...>
2951  13:04:53.175350 <... futex resumed> ) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
2951  13:04:53.175419 futex(0x7efc28442a28, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
2951  13:04:53.175469 futex(0x7efc28442a78, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=49999014} <unfinished ...>
2992  13:04:53.177624 <... futex resumed> ) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
2992  13:04:53.177661 futex(0x7efc2872dd78, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
2992  13:04:53.177704 futex(0x7efc2872ddc8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=9998753}) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
2992  13:04:53.187869 futex(0x7efc2872dd78, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
2992  13:04:53.187926 futex(0x7efc2872ddc8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=9998345}) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
2992  13:04:53.198107 futex(0x7efc2872dd78, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
2992  13:04:53.198173 futex(0x7efc2872ddc8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=9998906}) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
2992  13:04:53.208351 futex(0x7efc2872dd78, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
2992  13:04:53.208445 futex(0x7efc2872ddc8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=9998819} <unfinished ...>
2997  13:04:53.218546 <... futex resumed> ) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
2992  13:04:53.218607 <... futex resumed> ) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
2997  13:04:53.218627 futex(0x7efc298e0128, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1 <unfinished ...>
2992  13:04:53.218642 futex(0x7efc2872dd78, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1 <unfinished ...>
2997  13:04:53.218654 <... futex resumed> ) = 0
2992  13:04:53.218665 <... futex resumed> ) = 0
2997  13:04:53.218692 futex(0x7efc298e0178, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=99997816} <unfinished ...>
2992  13:04:53.218716 futex(0x7efc2872ddc8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=9998951} <unfinished ...>
2951  13:04:53.225620 <... futex resumed> ) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
2951  13:04:53.225685 futex(0x7efc28442a28, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
2951  13:04:53.225726 futex(0x7efc28442a78, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=49998661} <unfinished ...>
2992  13:04:53.228844 <... futex resumed> ) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
2992  13:04:53.228894 futex(0x7efc2872dd78, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
2992  13:04:53.228977 futex(0x7efc2872ddc8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=9998496}) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
2992  13:04:53.239167 futex(0x7efc2872dd78, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
2992  13:04:53.239237 futex(0x7efc2872ddc8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=9997919} <unfinished ...>
2615  13:04:53.248889 <... restart_syscall resumed> ) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
2615  13:04:53.248964 futex(0x7efc2802ee28, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
2615  13:04:53.249190 getrusage(RUSAGE_THREAD, {ru_utime={tv_sec=6, tv_usec=131107}, ru_stime={tv_sec=0, tv_usec=512377}, ru_maxrss=1415248, ru_ixrss=0, ru_idrss=0, ru_isrss=0, ru_minflt=3, ru_majflt=7, ru_nswap=0, ru_inblock=904, ru_oublock=0, ru_msgsnd=0, ru_msgrcv=0, ru_nsignals=0, ru_nvcsw=45187, ru_nivcsw=300}) = 0
2615  13:04:53.249267 futex(0x7efc2802ee78, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=299998402} <unfinished ...>
2992  13:04:53.249346 <... futex resumed> ) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
2992  13:04:53.249374 futex(0x7efc2872dd78, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
2992  13:04:53.249416 futex(0x7efc2872ddc8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=9999076}) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
2992  13:04:53.259600 futex(0x7efc2872dd78, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
2992  13:04:53.259669 futex(0x7efc2872ddc8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=9998583}) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
2992  13:04:53.269862 futex(0x7efc2872dd78, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
2992  13:04:53.269930 futex(0x7efc2872ddc8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=9998318} <unfinished ...>
2951  13:04:53.275876 <... futex resumed> ) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
2951  13:04:53.275954 futex(0x7efc28442a28, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
2951  13:04:53.276004 futex(0x7efc28442a78, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=49998347} <unfinished ...>
2992  13:04:53.280047 <... futex resumed> ) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
2992  13:04:53.280096 futex(0x7efc2872dd78, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
2992  13:04:53.280141 futex(0x7efc2872ddc8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=9998508}) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
2992  13:04:53.290333 futex(0x7efc2872dd78, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
2992  13:04:53.290392 futex(0x7efc2872ddc8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=9998348}) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
2992  13:04:53.300555 futex(0x7efc2872dd78, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
2992  13:04:53.300609 futex(0x7efc2872ddc8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=9998900}) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
2992  13:04:53.310804 futex(0x7efc2872dd78, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
2992  13:04:53.310878 futex(0x7efc2872ddc8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=9998305} <unfinished ...>
2997  13:04:53.318882 <... futex resumed> ) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
2997  13:04:53.318980 futex(0x7efc298e0128, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
2997  13:04:53.319107 futex(0x7efc298e0178, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=99998601} <unfinished ...>
2992  13:04:53.320991 <... futex resumed> ) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
2992  13:04:53.321028 futex(0x7efc2872dd78, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
2992  13:04:53.321071 futex(0x7efc2872ddc8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=9999116} <unfinished ...>
2951  13:04:53.326159 <... futex resumed> ) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
2951  13:04:53.326225 futex(0x7efc28442a28, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
2951  13:04:53.326265 futex(0x7efc28442a78, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=49997885} <unfinished ...>
2992  13:04:53.331172 <... futex resumed> ) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
2992  13:04:53.331224 futex(0x7efc2872dd78, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
2992  13:04:53.331276 futex(0x7efc2872ddc8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=9998352}) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
2992  13:04:53.341419 futex(0x7efc2872dd78, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
2992  13:04:53.341466 futex(0x7efc2872ddc8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=9998473}) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
2992  13:04:53.351601 futex(0x7efc2872dd78, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
2992  13:04:53.351647 futex(0x7efc2872ddc8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=9998359}) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
2992  13:04:53.361788 futex(0x7efc2872dd78, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
2992  13:04:53.361834 futex(0x7efc2872ddc8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=9998171}) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
2992  13:04:53.371984 futex(0x7efc2872dd78, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
2992  13:04:53.372032 futex(0x7efc2872ddc8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=9998375} <unfinished ...>
2951  13:04:53.376376 <... futex resumed> ) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
2951  13:04:53.376427 futex(0x7efc28442a28, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
2951  13:04:53.376465 futex(0x7efc28442a78, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=49999429} <unfinished ...>
2992  13:04:53.382147 <... futex resumed> ) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
2992  13:04:53.382195 futex(0x7efc2872dd78, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
2992  13:04:53.382228 futex(0x7efc2872ddc8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=9998186}) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
2992  13:04:53.392366 futex(0x7efc2872dd78, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
2992  13:04:53.392410 futex(0x7efc2872ddc8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=9998231}) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
2992  13:04:53.402554 futex(0x7efc2872dd78, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
2992  13:04:53.402602 futex(0x7efc2872ddc8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=9998401}) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
2992  13:04:53.412743 futex(0x7efc2872dd78, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
2992  13:04:53.412790 futex(0x7efc2872ddc8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=9998361} <unfinished ...>
2997  13:04:53.419251 <... futex resumed> ) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
2997  13:04:53.419300 futex(0x7efc298e0128, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
2997  13:04:53.419343 futex(0x7efc298e0178, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=99999061} <unfinished ...>
2992  13:04:53.422887 <... futex resumed> ) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
2992  13:04:53.422928 futex(0x7efc2872dd78, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
2992  13:04:53.422961 futex(0x7efc2872ddc8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=9998399} <unfinished ...>
2951  13:04:53.426558 <... futex resumed> ) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
2951  13:04:53.426595 futex(0x7efc28442a28, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
2951  13:04:53.426629 futex(0x7efc28442a78, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=49999301} <unfinished ...>
2992  13:04:53.433070 <... futex resumed> ) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
2992  13:04:53.433119 futex(0x7efc2872dd78, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
2992  13:04:53.433154 futex(0x7efc2872ddc8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=9998445}) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
2992  13:04:53.443295 futex(0x7efc2872dd78, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
2992  13:04:53.443341 futex(0x7efc2872ddc8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=9998386}) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
2992  13:04:53.453473 futex(0x7efc2872dd78, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
2992  13:04:53.453522 futex(0x7efc2872ddc8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=9998338}) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
2992  13:04:53.463666 futex(0x7efc2872dd78, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
2992  13:04:53.463712 futex(0x7efc2872ddc8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=9998111} <unfinished ...>
3002  13:04:53.471612 futex(0x7efc283e7a7c, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
3002  13:04:53.471696 futex(0x7efc29998f7c, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
2924  13:04:53.471717 <... restart_syscall resumed> ) = 0
2924  13:04:53.471734 futex(0x7efc283e7a28, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
2924  13:04:53.471769 mprotect(0x7efc31817000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
2924  13:04:53.471815 mprotect(0x7efc31817000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = 0
2924  13:04:53.471849 mprotect(0x7efc31818000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
2924  13:04:53.472428 futex(0x7efc2802c67c, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
2614  13:04:53.472463 <... futex resumed> ) = 0
2924  13:04:53.472473 futex(0x7efc283e7a78, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
2614  13:04:53.472482 futex(0x7efc2802c628, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
2614  13:04:53.472508 futex(0x7efc28028e78, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
2612  13:04:53.472530 <... futex resumed> ) = 0
2612  13:04:53.472544 futex(0x7efc28028e28, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
2612  13:04:53.472569 futex(0x7efc28027278, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
2611  13:04:53.472592 <... futex resumed> ) = 0
2611  13:04:53.472610 futex(0x7efc28027228, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
2611  13:04:53.472640 futex(0x7efc2802aa78, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
2992  13:04:53.473808 <... futex resumed> ) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
2992  13:04:53.473849 futex(0x7efc2872dd78, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
2992  13:04:53.473891 futex(0x7efc2872d978, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
2612  13:04:53.474207 sched_yield()     = 0
2614  13:04:53.474236 sched_yield( <unfinished ...>
2613  13:04:53.474249 <... futex resumed> ) = 0
2614  13:04:53.474260 <... sched_yield resumed> ) = 0
2613  13:04:53.474271 futex(0x7efc2802aa28, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1 <unfinished ...>
2611  13:04:53.474283 sched_yield( <unfinished ...>
2613  13:04:53.474295 <... futex resumed> ) = 0
2611  13:04:53.474306 <... sched_yield resumed> ) = 0
2613  13:04:53.474317 futex(0x7efc283e7a78, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1 <unfinished ...>
2612  13:04:53.474335 sched_yield()     = 0
2614  13:04:53.474365 sched_yield()     = 0
2611  13:04:53.474414 sched_yield( <unfinished ...>
2613  13:04:53.474425 <... futex resumed> ) = 1
2611  13:04:53.474436 <... sched_yield resumed> ) = 0
2612  13:04:53.474449 sched_yield( <unfinished ...>
2924  13:04:53.474460 <... futex resumed> ) = 0
2612  13:04:53.474470 <... sched_yield resumed> ) = 0
2924  13:04:53.474480 futex(0x7efc283e7a28, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1 <unfinished ...>
2614  13:04:53.474492 sched_yield( <unfinished ...>
2924  13:04:53.474503 <... futex resumed> ) = 0
2614  13:04:53.474514 <... sched_yield resumed> ) = 0
2924  13:04:53.474525 futex(0x7efc283e7a7c, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
2611  13:04:53.474544 sched_yield( <unfinished ...>
2613  13:04:53.474569 futex(0x7efc283e7a7c, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1 <unfinished ...>
2612  13:04:53.474581 futex(0x7efc28028e7c, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
2614  13:04:53.474600 futex(0x7efc2802c678, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
2924  13:04:53.474610 <... futex resumed> ) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
2613  13:04:53.474619 <... futex resumed> ) = 0
2924  13:04:53.474627 futex(0x7efc283e7a28, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL <unfinished ...>
2613  13:04:53.474635 futex(0x7efc283e7a28, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1 <unfinished ...>
2924  13:04:53.474642 <... futex resumed> ) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
2613  13:04:53.474650 <... futex resumed> ) = 0
2924  13:04:53.474658 futex(0x7efc283e7a28, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1 <unfinished ...>
2613  13:04:53.474666 futex(0x7efc2802aa7c, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
2924  13:04:53.474673 <... futex resumed> ) = 0
2611  13:04:53.474681 <... sched_yield resumed> ) = 0
2924  13:04:53.474689 futex(0x7efc28028e7c, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1 <unfinished ...>
2611  13:04:53.474697 futex(0x7efc2802727c, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
2924  13:04:53.474707 <... futex resumed> ) = 1
2612  13:04:53.474715 <... futex resumed> ) = 0
2924  13:04:53.474723 futex(0x7efc283e7a78, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
2612  13:04:53.474732 futex(0x7efc28028e28, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
2612  13:04:53.474757 futex(0x7efc2802c678, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1 <unfinished ...>
2614  13:04:53.474772 <... futex resumed> ) = 0
2612  13:04:53.474781 <... futex resumed> ) = 1
2614  13:04:53.474790 futex(0x7efc2802c628, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
2612  13:04:53.474829 futex(0x7efc2802c628, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1 <unfinished ...>
2614  13:04:53.474838 futex(0x7efc2802c628, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1 <unfinished ...>
2612  13:04:53.474848 <... futex resumed> ) = 0
2614  13:04:53.474856 <... futex resumed> ) = 0
2612  13:04:53.474865 futex(0x7efc28028e78, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
2614  13:04:53.474874 futex(0x7efc2802aa7c, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
2613  13:04:53.474895 <... futex resumed> ) = 0
2614  13:04:53.474903 futex(0x7efc2802c67c, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
2613  13:04:53.474911 futex(0x7efc2802aa28, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
2613  13:04:53.474932 futex(0x7efc283e7a78, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1 <unfinished ...>
2924  13:04:53.474944 <... futex resumed> ) = 0
2613  13:04:53.474952 <... futex resumed> ) = 1
2924  13:04:53.474959 futex(0x7efc283e7a28, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL <unfinished ...>
2613  13:04:53.474967 futex(0x7efc283e7a28, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1 <unfinished ...>
2924  13:04:53.474975 <... futex resumed> ) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
2613  13:04:53.474983 <... futex resumed> ) = 0
2924  13:04:53.474991 futex(0x7efc283e7a28, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1 <unfinished ...>
2613  13:04:53.474999 futex(0x7efc2802aa78, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
2924  13:04:53.475006 <... futex resumed> ) = 0
2924  13:04:53.475024 futex(0x7efc2802727c, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
2611  13:04:53.475043 <... futex resumed> ) = 0
2924  13:04:53.475051 futex(0x7efc283e7a7c, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
2611  13:04:53.475059 futex(0x7efc28027228, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
2611  13:04:53.475080 futex(0x7efc28028e78, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1 <unfinished ...>
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems to have been abandoned.

Comment: The question is still valid and unanswered

Answer (score 0):

How big is your CSV file?

Also, I do not see any indexes created for lot of MATCH/MERGE statements you are using. Are they created before hand? If there are no indexes, it can explain the time taken.

It would be good if you can post the output for ":schema" command.

Since you are using SSD, 2 GB should be usable. May be you want to reduce the commit size to use less heap.

Comment: the index on city is in place as we can see in the code above.

Comment: the index on city is in place as we can see in the code above.